# Can I rely on TCHAR's definition to make the correct assumptions about the charset I'm using?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I'm revisiting an old MFC hobby project and trying to make it more Unicode-friendly. As such I've been replacing all instances of `char` with `TCHAR`, `strlen()` with `_tcslen()` and so on.

However, [I just discovered](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e20bbe74-4484-4ec5-978e-cf86fb2fe21f/getting-the-number-of-characters-in-a-tchar-string?forum=vclanguage) that these types and functions aren't actually compatible with **all** language charsets. For example, Japanese characters are apparently represented by three bytes, not one:

> I would like to know the number of characters in a TCHAR array or TCHAR*. Unfortunately, every length function I can find (_tcslen(), even wstring::length()) seems to be returning the number of BYTES, not characters...a Japanese character counts as three and a Roman character counts as one.

However, [this Microsoft documentation page](https://developer.rhino3d.com/guides/cpp/using-sizeof-with-tchar-wchar-t/) suggests that using `TCHAR`s will keep you safe in all instances:

> To be safe in all cases, you should use the following convention when dealing with TCHARs:
>
> ```
> TCHAR tchBuffer[24];
> GetWindowText( hWnd, tchBuffer, sizeof(tchBuffer)/sizeof(TCHAR));
> ```
>
> In doing this, your code will be safe when compiled as either MBCS or UNICODE.

Is this true? Or will a multibyte charset such as a Japanese one result in UB? MTIA :-)

Comment: You should simply use wchar_t everywhere. The mentioned ms example only shows that use of `TCHAR` will allow the given code snippet to work properly when compiled with or without UNICODE support enabled. Note that `GetWindowText` requires buffer size, not string length.

Comment: @VTT no, GetWindowText requires length not size

Comment: @Kenny VTT is right. Don't use TCHAR. Use wchar_t.

Comment: To be consistent, when using `wchar_t` everywhere, one should also use explicit APIs, this means call the wide versions where possible (e. g. `GetWindowTextW`). Newer APIs usually only have a wide version, so these may not have a `W` suffix but still deal with UTF-16 input/output.

Comment: TCHAR vs wchar_t is a personal preference (when UNICODE is #define'd) and just switching to wchar_t does not fix incomplete characters chopped off at some unsafe offset.

Comment: It is "safe" in that you avoid buffer overflows and UB, but whether the results are properly encoded or linguistically meaningful is another story. Even with UTF-16, you have to be careful not to separate surrogates, and you also may not wish to separate combining characters from their base. The `_tcslen` and `wstring::length` functions return the length in code units, which is usually what you are interested in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really need to decide what the principal api is your application targets.

If, as you have it tagged, it is MFC based, you should be using MFC's c++ string representation, CString, and its rules for dealing with Ansi and Unicode on the Windows platform.

Likewise, if you are writing against the windows API principally, then your defined types are: CHAR, TCHAR and WCHAR for character literals, and *STR, *TSTR, and *WSTR for string buffers.

If you are writing a c++ application first - which happens to be implemented on windows - then prefer the std: types such as std:string and std:wstring

And lastly, if you want to represent strings via their C representations, then char*, wchar_t*, and if you want to be able to switch between unicode and ansi dynamically, then _tchar* and its helper types defined in .

**Switching between Ansi and Uniocode**
Of all the types, CString, TCHAR, *TSTR and _tchar will switch between an 8 and 16 bit type when you switch the compiler between Ansi and Unicode.

But really - Compiling applications as Ansi:
* inefficient as the Windows API has been nativley unicode for a while now so all api calls in an Ansi app that have string parameters are forced to convert all their in parameters on the way in and out parameters on the way out.
* Prone to data loss as an Ansi application can (almost) never work with characters from two different code pages as the same time.

**What can Ansi/MBCS safely encode anyway**
The Windows API defines an "Ansi Code Page". I don't know why its called Ansi, but you get the current one by calling `GetACP`. If this is set to, for e.g. CP_LATIN1, then attempts to load, process, input or deal with japanese, korean, etc characters will fail. This is a system wide default set in the regional settings control panel, so usually you should have the correct code page for the local user.

If you are using c-runtime functions then you need to call `setlocale` to ensure *it* knows what encoding you are using. I'm not sure if std::string uses the c locale or if theres a std:: abstraction of this idea. The point is, be aware of which string abstraction you are principally using, and use that, so you don't have to pepper your code with calls to all the different possible local / code page apis just because some bloody ?'s or blocks popped up in a string again.

**On the hand: Utf8**
On the other hand, the rest of the industry has gone in the other direction and Linux, MacOs, and correspondingly most cross platform libraries deal with unicode characters using Utf8 encoding. Which encodes all possible unicode characters with no messing around with locales or code pages or any of that nonsense. And all with the very cross platform friendly "char*".
Thus, if writing cross platform code is important to you, then you will NOT be using wchar_t or any of the wide character types.
Windows 10 finally added Utf8 as a possible Ansi code page BUT: Its a system setting that users must opt in to, so your application cannot declare, or rely on it being enabled. I don't know if it is possible to simply set it as the current thread code page, and I also don't know if any c-runtimes are compatible / take advantage of this to provide a seamless "closer to posix" experience where you can just expect strings to work.

Of course the caveat here is that "characters" can now be encoded with between 1 and possibly 6 bytes long.

**Byte length vs Characters**
Not sure what you want here. You generally don't want functions like *strlen to return the number of characters, as you are going (typically) to be using their results to allocate buffers of memory. They should however be returning a count not in bytes, but in the natural allocation unit of the character you are dealing with. i.e. wcslen("hello") should return 5, regardless of the width of wchar_t, which can be 2 or 4 bytes.

**wchar_t**
wchar_t is a horrible type as the c/c++ standard does not define its width. Some compilers have it as a 2byte unit, others 4 bytes. As a 2 byte unit it is only wide enough to store characters from unicodes "BMP" or basic multilingual plane, but there are characters that cannot be stored in a single UCS2 / UTF-16 character. If you want to be 100% safe, then you must use char16_t, char32_t or whatever you specifically need. wchar_t is not the safe option.

All told the situation is entirely hateful:

- You can't use plain-old-char's everywhere and depend on utf-8 as a sensible default because windows is Utf-16 native and using an 8 bit character set is terribly inefficient,
- and you are never guaranteed to be able to expect utf-8 so you're likely to be subject randomly to a lossy encoding.
- You can't use wchar_t everywhere as its different sizes on different platforms.
- If you have access to a stable Utf-16 :- posix platforms use plain old char* buffers with utf8 for everything resulting in the inverse performance issues on those platforms, and you still have to deal with the theoretical multi-unit character.
- Using the TCHAR / _tchar types and utilizing Visual Studios's Compiler for Unicode / Multibyte Character set switch is just intolerable as it adds lots of extra noise to your application, and doesn't really help with cross platform portability as all the _t*** functions are only part of the ms c-runtime.

Comment: The UTF-8 encoding scheme allows for code points to be encoded with up to 6 code units in theory. In practice, the Unicode Consortium defines encoding sequences with up to 4 code units. The `std::basic_string` implementations do not use C locales; there's simply nothing in the Standard C++ string types that depends on locales. They are `std::vector`'s, essentially, with a slightly larger interface to accommodate for string-like operations.

Comment: Wow thanks for the really detailed post +1 I will work on switching all the code to UTF-16 only I guess. This probably won't end up getting distributed anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, using wchar_t produces better results.

MFC was designed at a time where char was normally used, and multibyte character sets were only capable of encoding one language (e.g. Shift-JIS is an encoding for Japanese characters).

Since then, wchar_t has taken over as a usable set (on Windows wchar_t is an unsigned short, and encodes UTF-16).

My recommendation would be to convert directly to wchar_t, and ignore the tchar intermediate position.

UTF-16 does encode some characters with a multiple number of int16 values

Answer (score 0):

> In doing this, your code will be safe when compiled as either MBCS or UNICODE.

This is not true, regardless of which basic character type you are using.

Chopping a unknown string at arbitrary/buffer-size offsets is never safe. UTF-16 (`wchar_t` on Windows platforms) has [surrogate pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U+010000_to_U+10FFFF) and even if you switch to UTF-32 you would still have issues with [decomposed combining characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character), [digraphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraph_(orthography)#In_Unicode) and color modifiers.

Use `GetStringType` the get information about a specific character and/or use `CharNext` to walk the string to find a somewhat suitable stopping point.